# Intellisense Filter for Derived Members

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper, intellisense

Anyone that uses R# will know that if you have a method with an abstract class parameter - the intellisense will be filtered to just members which derive from that base.

Is there anyway to get the same behavior out of visual studio without Resharper?

Thanks.

Jon